# How to use FileTable with .NET Core application server side processing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I would like some advise about the schema that I would to implement to my .Net App.
I want to use FileTable with my .NET Core application where I must create a relationship of this FileTable with another simple table (e.g Document.cs). To improve the performance to render the files in application I will use server side processing.

I've put the FileController

```
var customerData = (from tempcustomer in _fileRepository.FileTableRoot select tempcustomer);
```

The FileTable is not mapped and I defined the ApplicationDbContext as follow

```
 public class FileContext : DbContext
{
    public FileContext(DbContextOptions<FileContext> options) : base(options)
    { }
           
    public DbSet<FileTableRoot> FileTableRoot { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<FileTableRoot>().HasNoKey().ToTable("FileTableRoot",t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations()); 
      
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }

}
```

FileTableRoot is not recognize in customerData
In brief I can't access the FileTable.
The FileTable is located : \servername\PartageData\wSerie\wSerieDir

Thanks to your help!

Comment: No answer. This means that's shema it's not possible.

Comment: @Toremikoo I've seen your post and I would like to know if you have your code in github I'm very interested to apply it